# Is there a way to call a python script to do some steps when i do a maven clean package in java?

Tags: python, java, spring, maven, jsonschema

I have a Spring Boot project with different yaml's and i want to create Json Schema for which one of them, but automatically, when i do a Maven clean package.

I found out about [openapi2jsonschema](https://github.com/instrumenta/openapi2jsonschema) but i don't know how to use it in my project to do what i want. I tried to install by hand, but when i do a

`pip install openapi2jsonschema`

i receive the next error:

```
`C:\\Users\\Administrator\>pip install openapi2jsonschema`
`Collecting openapi2jsonschema`
`Using cached openapi2jsonschema-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)`
`Collecting click\<8.0,\>=7.0 (from openapi2jsonschema)`
`Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama\<0.5.0,\>=0.4.1 in c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from openapi2jsonschema) (0.4.6)
Collecting jsonref\<0.3.0,\>=0.2.0 (from openapi2jsonschema)
Using cached jsonref-0.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting pyyaml\<6.0,\>=5.1 (from openapi2jsonschema)
Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[68 lines of output\]
C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\config\\setupcfg.py:293: \_DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
!!

              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
    
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
    
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
    
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 314, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 322, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 551, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 104, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kwh5il8k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]


note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

C:\\Users\\Administrator\>pip --version
pip 23.2.1 from C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip (python 3.11)`
```

Can i put this whole thing of pip install openSchema in a python script in maven, and then when i do a mvn clean package to work out without any errors...? thanks..

I watched  out different example to add this thing in a maven pom file, but i don't know how..

Comment: This looks to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Your real issue is the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for pip error was:

```
pip install "cython<3.0.0" wheel && pip install pyyaml==5.4.1 --no-build-isolation
```

and then you can run

```
pip install
```